# I am trying to use applet in my method

Tags: java, methods, applet, paint

I am creating a crossword puzzle program that displays the crossword through applet.  I'm attempting to create a method that will allow the user to enter his/her desired word. I call this `enterWord()`  My issue comes in when I try to implement applet into it.  I want my `enterWord()` method to allow the user to put in their `newWord`, the x coordinate and the y coordinate.

How can I change this code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;


public class crosswordMain extends Applet {

    String word;
    int wordlen;    

    public crosswordMain(){        
    }

    public void enterWord(String newWord, int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate){
        word = newWord;
        public void paint(Graphics g){            
            g.drawString(newWord, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        }
    }    

}
```

To make it work?  The issue comes at the `public void paint(Graphics g){` part.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are new to Java.  You have the paint() method inside enterWord().  This is not valid Java.  Perhaps you would be better off reviewing a Java tutorial and then an Applet tutorial.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot define a method inside another method in Java. 
To implement this,you could:
1. Create a **TextField** and store it in a global variable.
 `TextField inputLine = new TextField(15);`
2. Next,simply add this input string inside your `drawString` method like this:

`g.drawString(inputLine,x,y)`